# Please explain Subversion to me

Tags: svn

Every site and video I have seen introduces at least five new concepts in each sentence (for example, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjddHpBi8Go). It's like all these articles are in a whole other language. What is this Subversion thing in plain English, including how to go about implementing it?

Comment: No-one who has signed up to this site is really going to be asking this and meaning it.

Comment: @Michael, good edit, but you have to regret losing a little pizazz. :)

Comment: @amelvin Upvote says you're wrong.

Comment: Now you've cut that first line the question seems (almost) sensible.

Comment: @amelvin: Many, many people who have never worked on teams could ask this question with all sincerity. Even some who have worked on teams may not know much about revision control systems.

Comment: Subversion is that which tans your hide, and later, saves it.

Comment: @Joel-Potter The initial question (before heavy editing) started something like 'What the hell is this subversion thing' and from someone with a brand new account just looked like an attempt to farm reputation - the fact that none of the 8 good answers to it have been subsequently accepted is indicative.

Comment: @amelvin: Yeah I noticed that after I commented. The crux of the question is still valid though, however badly worded.

Comment: @amelvin forgive me if I'm wrong - but why do we should we care about "reputation" on big FAQ site. I could care less. For me and I'm sure a lot of others it's just a convenient place to ask questions. Reputation? Badges? c'mon already.

Answer (score 4):

> Every site and video I have seen
>   introduces at least 5 new concepts in
>   each sentence

Since you're not looking for a quick, dense introduction, I suggest that you take the time to read through the excellent [subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Subversion is a [revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), which means that it can be used to track all changes to your source code (or anything else you put in it).  If you cause some horrible bug and find out 6 weeks later, you can easily revert back to the original source.

Another common use is branching and merging, which allows several different developers/teams to work on their own copy (branch) of the source code at the same time.  When it's time to release, you can follow a consistent process to combine all of the different changes made by different teams.

To implement it, just go to the Subversion [web site](http://subversion.apache.org/) and install it.  The [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html) should answer most of your questions.  If you have more specific questions, you can search for/ask them here.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion is a tool used by people who want to manage the versions of their project.

Let's say that you are constantly changing a document. You can use Subversion to manage each revision. If you run your own Subversion server, you can commit changes to documents from your working directory (which contains all the documents you are working on) and *send* them to the server which then updates your repository so that the latest revisions of each document is displayed.

You can also have many collaborators who have access to your repository so you can all share and update changes.

Quick Definitions

- Document: Is just any file
- Repository: Is a location which you create to store the collection of documents
- Working copy/directory: Is the location on your local drive which contains the latest and most up to date (normally) version of your project.

Comment: Working Copy/Directory: The location ... which contains the _project files up to the last version you downloaded from the server, and any changes you have added_.

Answer (score 2):

The video linked to by the original question author was not intended as an introduction to SVN. Maybe [a video tutorial focused on *using* Subversion](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/series?id=95) will help.

Answer (score 2):

Not to confuse you even more, but there's Joel Spolsky's brilliant [**introduction to Mercurial**](http://hginit.com/) that is really, really easy to understand. It's a different version control system and different from Subversion in concept, so if you *have* to use Subversion, it's not for you. If you're still open in your choice, consider looking at it - it looks very interesting to me, I'm considering switching (I'm using Subversion currently.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement it (and it really is a good idea to use a tool like Subversion, [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) for short after the command-line executable, to keep old copies of your code) is to download [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.org/) which will add a context menu to Windows explorer.

Create an empty directory for SVN to keep its history data in, and then use right-click -> TortoiseSVN -> Create repository here

Then go to the area you want to work on your code and do right-click -> TortoiseSVN -> Checkout. In the dialog box that pops up browse to the repository you created.

Finally, after writing some code, use the TortoiseSVN menu to "Add" your source code files (the ones you write, not what the compiler creates) and then Commit. After each edit, run Commit again.

The Log menu item will show you the history and let you compare your code to earlier versions and even roll back changes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is also useful for team collaboration.  Every member can work on the same file at a time, and if the changes don't conflict, subversion will smoothly merge all of the changes.  If the changes conflict, subversion will flag these changes and make you fix them so that you don't lose/ruin someone else's work.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion (or SVN) is a version control system (others are CVS, Git, Mercurial). Version control systems are just a piece of software that sits on a computer somewhere (normally some sort of server that is always on and accessible) and which you can send updates of your work to. It is typically used for programming projects but can be used for all sorts of documents really. When you sync with the SVN server, it will save whatever changes you have made, but it won't forget how the documents were previously, so at any point you can 'revert' to an earlier version if you don't like some of your changes.

It provides a very useful way of backing up projects, but it also allows multiple people to work on the same project as they can all work on a copy of the project with SVN helping to merge all the changes later.

To use subversion you'll need to set it up on a server and then use an SVN client such as TortoiseSVN to commit changes to your project. If what you're working on is open source and free for other people to look at and use, then there are many free subversion services on the web such as [google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/).